# JUnit RestControllerTest for @PutMapping throws InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito, invocationtargetexception

I'm building a microservice using Spring Boot. I wrote an API with GET-, POST-, PUT-, DELETE- Methods, run the application and tested it using Postman - everything's working fine...

But testing the PUT-Method fails with

**java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<204> but was:<400>**

Running the test in debug-mode and stepping throw throws an InvocationTargetException:

[image: InvocatioTargetException]

**My RestController-Methods looks like this:**

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity updateSongById(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, @RequestBody @Validated 
SongDto songDto) {
    // TODO Add authorization
    SongDto song = songService.getSongById(id);
    if (song == null)
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    return new ResponseEntity(songService.updateSong(id, songDto), HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}
```

**songService.getSongById(id):**

```
@Override
public SongDto getSongById(Integer id) {
    return songMapper.songToSongDto(songRepository.findById(id)
        .orElseThrow(NotFoundException::new));
}
```

The SongRepository is just a simple Interface which extends JpaRepository<Song, Integer>.

My failing test looks like this:

```
@Test
void updateSongById_success() throws Exception {
    when(songService.updateSong(anyInt(), any(SongDto.class))).thenReturn(getValidSongDto());
    String songDtoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(getValidSongDto());
    mockMvc.perform(put("/rest/v1/songs/1")
            .content(songDtoJson)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
}
```

And getValidSongDto() just provides a Dto used in my tests:

```
private SongDto getValidSongDto() {
    return SongDto.builder()
            .id(1)
            .title("TestSongValid")
            .label("TestLabelValid")
            .genre("TestGenreValid")
            .artist("TestArtistValid")
            .released(1000)
            .build();
}
```

I really don't understand at the moment, what I did wrong to make this test fail and also couldn't find anything in the internet which helped me solving this problem, so far. So, therefor I'd be very thankful, if anybody could tell me what's wrong here and how to solve this issue.

Thank you very much!!

Comment: You didn't define anything for `songService.getSongById` which leads to `null` response and leading to a 400 error. In reality this will never occur as an exception will be thrown. That being said, your response is also strange, you give the status NO_CONTENT, but you are including content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value for `songService.getSongById` as shown below

```
@Test
void updateSongById_success() throws Exception {
    
    when(songService.getSongById(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(getValidSongDto());
    
    when(songService.updateSong(anyInt(), any(SongDto.class))).thenReturn(getValidSongDto());
    
    String songDtoJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(getValidSongDto());
    
    mockMvc.perform(put("/rest/v1/songs/1")
            .content(songDtoJson)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isNoContent());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works perfectly fine - my test is happy now and me too.

Comment: @Mahakala108, You can accept the answer, so others will know that answer is accepted